# Stop Slide Animation on Scroll

Tags: jquery

My WordPress based theme has a Content Slider based on JQuery. The Content Slider "slides" between each slide at a given time. I would like to stop  the animation when a user scrolls down on a page. And resume the animation when they scroll back all the way.

Can someone help me add to the code...

```js
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
 if(PEXETO.pendingVideoFunctions && PEXETO.pendingVideoFunctions.length){
  for(var i in PEXETO.pendingVideoFunctions){
   PEXETO.pendingVideoFunctions[i].call();
  }
 }
}


/**
 * This is the script for the content slider - it slides between different slides with
 * different animation. Each slide is composed of two sections and each of this section
 * is animated in a random effect.
 *
 * Dependencies:
 * - jQuery
 * - jQuery Easing : http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
 *
 * @author Pexeto
 * http://pexetothemes.com
 */
(function($) {
 "use strict";
 
 $.fn.pexetoContentSlider = function(options) {
  var defaults = {
   //set the default options (can be overwritten from the calling function)
   autoplay          : true,
   autoplayMobile    : false,
   animationInterval : 5000,
   //the interval between each animation when autoplay is true
   pauseOnHover      : true,
   //if true the animation will be paused when the mouse is
   // over the slider
   pauseInterval     : 5000,
   //the time that the animation will be paused after a click
   animationSpeed    : 400,
   easing            : 'easeOutSine',
   buttons           : true,
   //show the navigation buttons
   arrows            : true,
   thumbnailPreview  : true,
   //show the navigation arrows
   //selectors, classes and IDs
   ulSel             : '#cs-slider-ul',
   navigationId      : 'cs-navigation',
   selectedClass     : 'selected',
   firstBoxSel       : '.cs-content-left',
   secondBoxSel      : '.cs-content-right',
   centerBoxSel   : '.cs-content-centered',
   prevArrowClass    : 'cs-arrows cs-prev-arrow',
   nextArrowClass    : 'cs-arrows cs-next-arrow',
   loadingClass      : 'cs-loading'
  };


  var o            = $.extend(defaults, options),
   $root        = null,
   $parent      = null,
   $ul          = null,
   $nav         = null,
   $navLi       = null,
   $prevArrow   = null,
   $nextArrow   = null,
   itemNum      = 0,
   currentIndex = 0,
   timer        = 0,
   stopped      = true,
   inAnimation  = false,
   sliderHeight = 0,
   showEffects = ['slideLeft', 'slideRight', 'slideUp', 'slideDown'],
   showEffectNum = showEffects.length,
   slides = [],
   $newBgImage = null,
   $oldBgImage = null,
   defaultBg = '#252525',
   isIe8 = PEXETO.getBrowser().msie && PEXETO.getBrowser().version<=8,
   loadProgress = 0,
   videoPlaying = false,
   videoLoading = false,
   pendingVideoFunctions = [],
   mouseIn = false,
   supportsTransition = PEXETO.utils.supportsTransition(),
   isMobile = PEXETO.utils.checkIfMobile(),
   elTiming = isMobile ? 300 : 150;

  $root = $(this);
  $parent = $root.parent();
  $ul = $root.find(o.ulSel);

  if(typeof PEXETO.videoId === 'undefined'){
   PEXETO.videoId = 0;
  }


  /**
   * Inits the slider - calls the main functionality.
   */

  function init() {

   $root.addClass(o.loadingClass);

   //get the items number
   itemNum = $ul.find('li').each(function(i) {
    var $li = $(this),
     layout = $li.data('layout');


    slides[i] = {
     firstBox: layout === 'centered' ? $li.find(o.centerBoxSel) : $li.find(o.firstBoxSel),
     secondBox: layout === 'centered' ? null : $li.find(o.secondBoxSel),
     li:$li,
     layout:layout,
     animation:$li.data('animation')
    };

    if(o.thumbnailPreview && $li.data('thumbnail')){
     slides[i].thumbnail = $li.data('thumbnail');
    }

    if($li.data('bg_image_url')){
     slides[i].bgImage = $li.data('bg_image_url');
     slides[i].bgOpacity = $li.data('bg_image_opacity');
    }

    if($li.data('bg_align')){
     slides[i].bgAlign = $li.data('bg_align');
    }

    if($li.data('bg_style')){
     slides[i].bgStyle = $li.data('bg_style');
    }

    if($li.data('bg_color')){
     slides[i].bgColor = $li.data('bg_color');
     $parent.css({backgroundColor:slides[i].bgColor});
    }

    if($li.data('video')){
     slides[i].video = $li.data('video');
    }

   }).length;

   if(!o.arrows && isMobile && itemNum>=1){
    //show the arrows on mobile
    o.arrows = true;
   }

   if(!o.arrows || itemNum<=1){
    o.thumbnailPreview = false;
   }



   $.when(loadSlideImages(0,0), setSliderPadding()).done(function(){
    doOnImgLoaded();
    $root.removeClass(o.loadingClass);
    showSlide(0);
   });

   if(itemNum<=1){
    o.buttons=false;
    o.arrows=false;
    o.autoplay=false;
   }

   if(isMobile){
    o.autoplay=o.autoplayMobile;
    if(o.autoplayMobile){
     o.pauseOnHover = false;
    }
   }

   loadSlideImages(1,itemNum-1).done(doOnImgLoaded);
  }

  function doOnImgLoaded(){
   loadProgress+=0.5;
   if(loadProgress===1){
    //both the first image and the rest of the images have been loaded
    //init the slider functionality
    
    //set the navigation buttons
    setNavigation();
    bindEventHandlers();

    if(o.thumbnailPreview){
     setThumbnailPreviews(0);
    }

    //the images are loaded, start the animation
    if(o.autoplay) {
     startAnimation();
    }

   }
  }

  function loadSlideImages(firstIndex, lastIndex){
   var deferred = new $.Deferred(),
    progress = 0,
    imgSrcToLoad = [],
    imagesToLoad = [],
    imgNum = 0,
    imgLoaded = 0,
    img = null,
    i,
    onImgLoaded = function(){
     imgLoaded++;

     if(imgLoaded===imgNum){
      deferred.resolve();
     }
    };

   for(i=firstIndex; i<=lastIndex; i++){
    slides[i].li.find('img').each(function(){
     imgSrcToLoad.push($(this).attr('src'));
    });

    if(slides[i].bgImage){
     imgSrcToLoad.push(slides[i].bgImage);
    }

    if(o.thumbnailPreview && slides[i].thumbnail){
     imgSrcToLoad.push(slides[i].thumbnail);
    }
   }

   imgNum = imgSrcToLoad.length;

   for(i=0; i<imgNum; i++){
    img = new Image();
    img.src = imgSrcToLoad[i];
    imagesToLoad.push($(img));
   }

   if(imgNum===0){
    deferred.resolve();
   }else{
    for(i=0; i<imgNum; i++){
     imagesToLoad[i].pexetoOnImgLoaded({callback:onImgLoaded});
    }
   }

   return deferred;
  }

  function setSliderPadding(){
   var deferred = new $.Deferred(),
    $logoImg;

   if(isMobile || $root.parents('.content').length){
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred;
   }

   $logoImg = $('#logo-container').find('img');

   if($logoImg.length){
    $logoImg.pexetoOnImgLoaded({callback:function(){
     var logoHeight = $logoImg.height();
     $parent.css({paddingTop:logoHeight});

     deferred.resolve();
    }});
   }

   return deferred;
  }

  /**
   * Binds event handlers for the main slider functionality.
   */

  function bindEventHandlers() {

   if(o.buttons) {
    //add event handlers
    $nav.on({
     'click': doOnBtnClick,
     'slideChanged': doOnSlideChanged
    }, 'li');

   }

   if(o.arrows) {
    $prevArrow.on('click', function() {
     mouseIn = true;
     doOnArrowClick(false);
    });
    $nextArrow.on('click', function() {
     mouseIn = true;
     doOnArrowClick(true);
    });
   }



   //display/hide the navigation on $root hover
   $root.on({
    'mouseenter': doOnSliderMouseEnter,
    'mouseleave': doOnSliderMouseLeave
   });

   $(window).on('resize', function(){
    setSliderHeight(currentIndex);
    centerSlide(currentIndex);
   });
  }

  /**
   * Calls the functionality to change the current slide with another one.
   * @param  {int} index the index of the new slide
   */

  function changeSlide(index) {
   if(!inAnimation) {
    inAnimation = true;
    hideSlide(currentIndex);
    showSlide(index);
    currentIndex = index;

    if(o.thumbnailPreview){
     setThumbnailPreviews(index);
    }

    if(o.buttons) {
     $navLi.trigger('slideChanged');
    }
   }
  }

  function setThumbnailPreviews(index){
   var nextSlideIndex = getNextSlideIndex(index),
    prevSlideIndex = getPrevSlideIndex(index);
   setThumbnailPreview($nextArrow, nextSlideIndex);
   setThumbnailPreview($prevArrow, prevSlideIndex);
  }

  function setThumbnailPreview($arrow, index){
   var thumbnail = slides[index].thumbnail;
   $arrow.find('.cs-thumbnail').remove();
   
   if(thumbnail){
    $arrow.prepend('<img src="'+thumbnail+'" class="cs-thumbnail" />');
   }
  }


  /**
   * Adds navigation buttons to the slider and sets event handler functions to them.
   */

  function setNavigation() {
   var i, html = '';

   //generate the buttons
   if(o.buttons) {
    $nav = $('<ul />', {
     id: o.navigationId
    });
    for(i = 0; i < itemNum; i++) {
     html += '<li><span></span></li>';
    }
    $nav.html(html).appendTo($root).fadeIn(700);

    $navLi = $nav.find('li');
    $navLi.eq(0).addClass(o.selectedClass);
   }

   //generate the arrows
   if(o.arrows) {
    $prevArrow = $('<div />', {
     'class': o.prevArrowClass
    }).appendTo($root);
    $nextArrow = $('<div />', {
     'class': o.nextArrowClass
    }).appendTo($root);
   }

  }

  /***********************************************************************
   * EVENT HANDLER FUNCTIONS
   **********************************************************************/

  /**
   * On arrow click event handler. Calls a function to change the slide
   * depending on which arrow (previous/next) was clicked.
   * @param  {boolean} next whether the next arrow is clicked (set it to true)
   * or the previous one was cicked (set it to false)
   */

  function doOnArrowClick(next) {
   var index;
   if(next) {
    //next index will be the next item if there is one or the first item
    index = getNextSlideIndex(currentIndex);
   } else {
    //previous index will be the previous item if there is one or the last item
    index = getPrevSlideIndex(currentIndex);
   }
   if(!inAnimation) {
    pause();
   }
   changeSlide(index);
  }

  function getNextSlideIndex(index){
   return index + 1 < itemNum ? index + 1 : 0;
  }

  function getPrevSlideIndex(index){
   return index - 1 >= 0 ? index - 1 : itemNum - 1;
  }

  /**
   * On slider mouse enter event handler.
   */

  function doOnSliderMouseEnter() {
   if(o.buttons) {
    //show the buttons
    $nav.stop().fadeIn(function() {
     $nav.animate({
      opacity: 1
     }, 0);
    });
   }

   if(o.autoplay && o.pauseOnHover) {
    //pause the animation
    stopAnimation();
    mouseIn = true;
   }
  }

  /**
   * On slider mouse leave event handler.
   */

  function doOnSliderMouseLeave() {
   if(o.buttons) {
    //hide the buttons
    $nav.stop().animate({
     opacity: 0
    });
   }

   if(o.autoplay && o.pauseOnHover) {
    //resume the animation
    mouseIn = false;
    startAnimation();
   }
  }

  /**
   * On navigation button click event handler. Calls the functionality
   * to show the slide that corresponds to the button index.
   * @param  {object} e the event object
   */

  function doOnBtnClick(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   var index = $navLi.index($(this));
   if(!inAnimation) {
    pause();
   }
   if(currentIndex !== index) {
    changeSlide(index);
   }
  }

  /**
   * On slider change event handler. Sets the current button in the navigation
   * to be selected according to the current slide index.
   */

  function doOnSlideChanged() {
   var index = $navLi.index($(this));
   if(currentIndex === index) {
    $(this).addClass(o.selectedClass);
   } else {
    $(this).removeClass(o.selectedClass);
   }
  }

  /***************************************************************************
   * ANIMATION FUNCTIONS
   **************************************************************************/

  /**
   * Hides a slide with a random animation.
   * @param {int} index the index of the slide to be displayed
   */

  function hideSlide(index) {

   var slide = slides[index],
    $firstBox = slides[index].firstBox,
    $secondBox = slides[index].secondBox,
    finishHide = function($box){
     slide.li.hide();
     $box.find('.cs-element').removeClass('cs-animate');
    };

   if(slide.video){
    hideVideo(slide);
   }


   //hide the first box
   hideInnerElements($firstBox, function(){
    finishHide($firstBox);
   });

   //hide the second box
   if($secondBox){
    hideInnerElements($secondBox, function(){
     finishHide($secondBox);
    });
   }

   if($newBgImage){
    //fade out the background image
    $oldBgImage = $newBgImage;
    $oldBgImage.animate({opacity:0}, 1000, function(){
     $(this).remove();
     $oldBgImage = null;
    });
   }

  }

  function hideInnerElements($box, callback){
   var $elements = $box.find('.cs-element');
   $elements.css({opacity:0});
   if(callback){
    if(supportsTransition){
     $elements.last().on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function(){
      callback.call();
      $(this).off('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd');
     });
    }else{
     callback.call();
    }
   }
  }

  function centerSlide(index){
   var slide = slides[index];

   if(slide.layout=='centered'){
    var liHeight = slide.li.height(),
     ulHeight = Math.max(sliderHeight, parseInt($ul.css('minHeight'), 10));
    if(ulHeight > liHeight){
     slide.li.css({paddingTop:((ulHeight-liHeight)/2)});
    }
   }
  }

  /**
   * Displays a slide with a random animation.
   * @param {int} index the index of the slide to be displayed
   */

  function showSlide(index) {
   var slide = slides[index],
    animation = slide.animation === 'random' ? 
     showEffects[Math.floor(Math.random() * showEffectNum)] :
     slide.animation,
    //get a random effect
    $firstBox = slide.firstBox,
    $secondBox = slide.secondBox,
    lastBox = true;


   videoPlaying = false;
   slide.li.show();

   if(slide.video){
    initVideo(slide);
   }
   

   setSliderHeight(index);

   centerSlide(index);


   //show the background image
   if(slide.bgImage){
    var cssArgs = {backgroundImage:'url('+slide.bgImage+')'};
    if(slide.bgAlign){
     cssArgs.backgroundPosition = slide.bgAlign;
    }

    if(slide.bgStyle){
     //only the default style is parallax (background-attachment fixed), the other styles are scroll
     cssArgs.backgroundAttachment = 'scroll';
     if(slide.bgStyle==='contain'){
      cssArgs.backgroundSize = 'contain';
     }
    }

    $newBgImage = $('<div />', {'class':'full-bg-image'})
     .css(cssArgs)
     .insertBefore($root)
     .animate({opacity:slide.bgOpacity}, 1000);

    if(isIe8){
     new PEXETO.utils.bgCoverFallback($newBgImage).init();
    }

   }

   if(slide.bgColor){
    $parent.css({backgroundColor:'#'+slide.bgColor});
   }else if($parent.css('backgroundColor')!==defaultBg){
    $parent.css({backgroundColor:defaultBg});
   }
   
   $.when(
    (function(){
     //animate the first box elements with a delay
     var def = new $.Deferred();
     setTimeout(function() {
      showInnerElements($firstBox, animation, def);
     }, o.animationSpeed / 2 + 150);
     return def;
    }()),
    (function(){
     //animate the second box elements
     var def = new $.Deferred();
     if($secondBox){
      showInnerElements($secondBox, animation, def);
     }else{
      def.resolve();
     }
     return def;
    }())
   ).done(function(){
    setEndAnimation();
   });
  }

  function initVideo (slide) {
   videoLoading = true;
   pause();

   var videoElId = 'video-'+(PEXETO.videoId++),
    initElVideo = function(){
     var player = new YT.Player(videoElId, {
             height: '100%',
             width: '100%',
             videoId: slide.video,
             events: {
               'onReady': function(){
       slide.$videoWrap
        .animate({opacity:1}, 700)
        .parent().removeClass('loading');
       videoLoading = false;
       startAnimation();

       
               },
               'onStateChange': function(event){
       if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        stopAnimation();
        videoPlaying = true;
       }
               }
             }
           });

     PEXETO.init.ieIframeFix(); //fix the iframe z-index bug on IE

    };

   slide.$videoWrap = slide.li.find('.cs-video:first').css({opacity:0});
   $('<div />', {'id':videoElId}).appendTo(slide.$videoWrap);
   slide.$videoWrap.parent().addClass('loading');

   if(window.YT && window.YT.Player){
    initElVideo();
   }else{
    if(!PEXETO.pendingVideoFunctions){
     PEXETO.pendingVideoFunctions = [];
    }
    PEXETO.pendingVideoFunctions.push(initElVideo);
   }
  }

  function hideVideo(slide){
   slide.$videoWrap.animate({opacity:0}, function(){
    slide.$videoWrap.empty();
   });
  }

  function showInnerElements($box, animation, def){
   var i = 100,
    settings = getPositionPropertySettings(animation),
    animateProperty = settings.property,
    mult = settings.mult,
    pos = 150*mult,
    $elements = $box.find('.cs-element');

   if(!$elements.length){
    def.resolve();
    return;
   }

   $elements.each(function(index){
    var $el = $(this),
     args = {opacity:0};

    if(!isMobile){
     args[animateProperty] = pos;
    }

    $el.css(args);

    setTimeout(function(){
     var showArgs = {opacity:1},
      args;
     showArgs[animateProperty] = 0;
     args = [showArgs];

     if(index===$elements.length-1){
      //add a callback function to be executed after the
      //element animation
      args.push(function(){
       def.resolve();
      });
     }

     $el.addClass('cs-animate');
     $.fn.pexetoTransit.apply($el, args);
     
    }, i);
    i+=elTiming;
    pos = pos > 20 ? pos-20 : pos;
   });
  }

  function getPositionPropertySettings(animation){
   var settings = {
    'slideLeft' : {property: 'left', mult: 1},
    'slideRight' : {property: 'left', mult: -1},
    'slideUp' : {property: 'top', mult: 1},
    'slideDown' : {property: 'top', mult: -1}
   };

   return settings[animation];

  }

  function setSliderHeight(index){

   sliderHeight = slides[index].li.height();

   $ul.css({height: sliderHeight});
  }


  /**
   * Starts the animation.
   */

  function startAnimation() {
   if(o.autoplay && stopped && !videoPlaying) {
    if(o.pauseOnHover && mouseIn){
     //the mouse is still within the container
     return;
    }
    stopped = false;
    timer = window.setInterval(callNextSlide, o.animationInterval);
   }
  }

  /**
   * Sets the inAnimation variable to false.
   */

  function setEndAnimation() {
   inAnimation = false;
  }

  /**
   * Triggers a changeSlide event to display the next slide.
   */

  function callNextSlide() {
   if(!videoLoading){
    var nextIndex = (currentIndex < itemNum - 1) ? (currentIndex + 1) : 0;
    changeSlide(nextIndex);
   }
  }

  /**
   * Stops the animation.
   */

  function stopAnimation() {
   if(o.autoplay) {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
    timer = -1;
    stopped = true;
   }
  }

  /**
   * Pauses the animation.
   */

  function pause() {
   if(o.autoplay) {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
    timer = -1;
    if(!stopped) {
     window.setTimeout(startAnimation, o.pauseInterval);
    }
    stopped = true;
   }
  }


  init();

 };

}(jQuery));
```